# Can Javascript detect the moment that the default font size is changed inside browser settings?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

**Question)** Can Javascript detect the moment that the default font size is changed inside browser settings?

For example in Google Chrome > Settings > Customize fonts > Font size

When the default font size is changed the layouts in every open tab immediately change.  Does Javascript have an event to detect this instant change?

I looked through  [MDN: Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) but I don't see anything that might accomplish this.  Is there maybe another technique to detect this instant change?

Comment: Does the resize event handler fire?

Comment: @epascarello  Nope I tried that one.  resize detects when the browser width or height changes, but not the content inside of it.

Comment: my guess is only way to detect it is to basically monitor some element for the size to change. not 100% sure if mutation observer would fire or not.

Comment: Since the user has to leave the web page to alter the default font size, would the focus and blur events of the window meet your needs?  On blur, record the size of an element affected by a font change and, on focus, compare its size against the recorded size.  If different, invoke the desired function.  I found your two questions on this topic because I was looking for a similar event and have not found one.  This works but do you know of any case in which it would fail? Can a user change the default font without leaving the web page?

Comment: A problem with this approach is that the browser needs time to adjust the page elements for the change in default font size; thus, onfocus, a delay is required before querying element geometry. Some approach must be taken to avoid displaying a "jerk" on adjustment. In going from 72px to 9px, on my 4GB of RAM and 2.2Ghz CPU, it needs 500ms to adjust before can query the dimensions. The most difficult issue in my case, was that needed to set the height of some elements and the scrollbars would appear on resize just long enough for query to give wrong value, then disappear leaving unwanted space.